# how can I diff two ARM32 binaries at assembly code level?

Tags: ida

I'm looking for a tool like Beyond Compare, meld, kdiff, etc. which can be used to compare two disassembled binaries. I know that there's binary (hex) comparison, which shows difference by hex values, but I'm looking for something that shows op-codes and arguments.

Anyone knows something that can help ?

[image: image below is x86, i want ARM32]

Answer (score 4):

[BinnDiff](https://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html) and [Diaphora](https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora) could be helpful for what you want.